# How to save a <IPython.core.display.HTML> ? I need to save a <pandas.DataFrame.style> as a image or as a HTML file

Tags: python, html, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How to save a <IPython.core.display.HTML>,
I need to save a <pandas.DataFrame.style> as a image or as a HTML file.

I am using Jupyter Notebook, I stylized my Pandas DataFrame displays, and I need to save the DataFrame output displays as an image (png) or as HTML file, I tried the code lines, see below, the file saves as HTML but I get a blank page when opened with a bowser.

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B":['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df_styler = HTML(df.style.hide_index().render()).data

with open('df_styler.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df_styler)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue by looking at the HTML code, the code is perfectly find...
On my PC, I am using the Dark theme Windows settings...
Changing the Windows settings theme revealed that the DataFrame was indeed saved as a HTML table, the table font color was defaulted to 'black', and my browser window background color was also set as black...